# How to change the UIDocumentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated background color to white?

Tags: ios, ios4

I use the `UIDocumentInteractionController` controller to present images by calling `presentPreviewAnimated`.

It works great, but when I load transparent images, they are being presented on a black background and look like a mess.

I would like to change the background color to white.

Comment: you need to set clearColor first.